# getting 502 from ingress on my simple signup/login app with mongodb. nginx ingress ip not matching api requests ip

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I started a very simple login and signup app with MongoDB.
I got the website working on google cloud but I couldn't set the api request correctly.
I am getting 502 bad gateway from nginx.
the website is on: http://35.188.82.6
and the github repo is on: https://github.com/damonleelcx/PureSign

```
2020/10/11 23:44:23 [error] 451#451: *1143751 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.128.0.4, server: _, request: "POST /api/users/register HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.0.2.43:3000/api/users/register", host: "35.188.82.6", referrer: "http://35.188.82.6/"

2020/10/11 23:44:23 [error] 451#451: *1143751 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.128.0.4, server: _, request: "POST /api/users/register HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.0.1.48:3000/api/users/register", host: "35.188.82.6", referrer: "http://35.188.82.6/"

2020/10/11 23:44:23 [error] 451#451: *1143751 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.128.0.4, server: _, request: "POST /api/users/register HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.0.0.80:3000/api/users/register", host: "35.188.82.6", referrer: "http://35.188.82.6/"

10.128.0.4 - - [11/Oct/2020:23:44:23 +0000] "POST /api/users/register HTTP/1.1" 502 552 "http://35.188.82.6/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36" 546 0.004 [default-server-cluster-ip-service-3000] [] 10.0.2.43:3000, 10.0.1.48:3000, 10.0.0.80:3000 0, 0, 0 0.003, 0.001, 0.000 502, 502, 502 1c28cfe67d44718379c08c826559df90

10.0.0.1 - - [11/Oct/2020:23:51:56 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 993 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/601.7.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.2 Safari/601.7.7" 189 0.002 [default-client-cluster-ip-service-8080] [] 
10.0.2.44:8080 993 0.003 200 875335eee9ecf00b0140ac95af93d3d6
```

"http://10.0.x.xx:3000/api/users/register" is not matching my server ip "35.188.82.6". BTW, my express server is listening on localhost.

Please help~~~ Thanks!!!

Comment: how many nodes did you install for kubernetes ?

Comment: 3 nodes on google cloud platform. 3 replicas for client and 3 replicas for server. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**503** indicates that there is an issue with server/pod not being able to handle the request (usually due to server being overloaded or down).

```
Ingress -> Service --(Place where the communication issue exists)--> Pod
```

So your problem lies withing server (`expressjs`) configuration.  The `localhost` argument [here](https://github.com/damonleelcx/PureSign/blob/b8f9a10cdb269815e5ca6792489287edf8a6155e/server/server.js#L51) is optional.

Once you remove it, server will then listen on all of the interfaces. This will allow you to get your traffic towards pod.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. Do please look at the vue.config.js and nginx/default.conf file under the client folder. I wonder how I would change them if I remove the locahost from the express server?

Comment: thank you very much!!! I changed all the "localhost" literals to "0.0.0.0". Then It worked perfectly!!!!